# Flutter/Dart can't seem to get Google Oauth signin working

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth

I'm a newbie, so please be gentle .

I'm using VSCode to write a Dart/Flutter app that I want to use Google Oauth on for signing in  and subsequently sending emails. I'm using this snippet of code from one of Johannes Milke's video tutorials. **isSigned** is comes back as true. But **currentUser** (and everything else) comes back as null. As you can see, I've tried different versions of a print statement to try to see what's going on.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks ... Jeff

````
class GoogleAuthApi {
  static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['https://mail.google.com/']);
  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    var x = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
    var y = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    print('Signed In: ... $x ... $y ');
    if (await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn()) {
      print('Signed In: await ${_googleSignIn.isSignedIn()} ... ');
      print('Current User: await ${_googleSignIn.currentUser}');
      return _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    } else {
      return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
  }```
````